# can I set # of open files to be umlimited?

Tags: 14.04, ulimit

I am using ubuntu, but setting `/etc/security/limits.conf` to beyond 999999 doesn't seem to work (reverts back to 1024). Is there a way to set this to be unlimited?

Comment: I am curious about the use case of setting it to unlimited.

Comment: it is a program that divides up an input file into fixed chunks and streaming each chunk to a different machine. The # of file handles required depends on the size of the input file. I have no control over the implementation.

Comment: you probably also need to set the system wide max open files. (`sysctl -w fs.file-max=999999` ) since that would be the next limit the system will hit. If that is currenlty 1024 I'd assume that might be taken over your value.

Comment: I get similar to you, however, slightly different limits. 1048576 (0X100000) works, but 1048577 (0X100001) does not work.

Comment: The limit of 1048576 might be the same as sysctl fs.nr_open. (`sysctl -a | grep "^fs\."`) However, if I try to increase fs.nr_open, it gets restored after re-boot.